# callback not fetching record in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, node-modules

i want to pass email in `postman` and want to print the fetched `json data` to `console`. but it is not `fetching any data`. so help me to solve this issue

mongoconnect.js

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
var dbo=null;

exports.connection=function(){
    if(dbo!=null) return 

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
   dbo = db.db("hospital_api");

});
}

var get = function (){
    return dbo;
}

exports.email=function(r){
    get().dbo.collection("doctor").find({"email":r}).toArray(function(err,result)
    {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result)
        return result;
    })
}
```

doctor.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var validator = require('validator');
var mongo= require('./mongoconnect')
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.post('/',function(req,res)
    {
        d=mongo.email(req.body.email)
        console.log(d);
    })

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `export.email`, you have a typo

```
exports.email = function(r) {
    get().collection("doctor").find({"email":r})  // no ".dbo" after get()
```